# Modulus Implication

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If $a, \ b, \ c, \ d$ are integers and $a \equiv b \pmod c$ then $d^a \equiv d^b \pmod c$. True or false?

I changed this statement to  If $a,b,c,d$ are integers and $c\mid (a-b)$ then $c\mid (d^a - d^b)$ for the sake of my understanding.

Any hints on how this statement can be proven or disproven?

Comment: The following is true: if $\gcd(d, c) = 1$ and $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function, then $$a \equiv b \mod \varphi(c) \implies d^a \equiv d^b \bmod c $$

Answer (score 3):

It is false. Take $c=3, a=5,b=2,d=-1$ for a counterexample.

Comment: is there a systematic way to prove this? or is proof by counterexample the only way

Comment: @baba: This is one of those problems where just about every example is a counter-example, so all you need for a systematic approach is "pick something, check it doesn't work".